# iOS 9: Application Transport Security plist configurations

Tags: ios, security, plist, nsurl, ios9

I am currently working on a application that uses both HTTPS endpoints and HTTP endpoints. Now I want to conform to Application Transport Security for iOS9 by making a `NSExceptionDomains`dictionary in the plist, but the amount of 3rd party endpoints my application hits is dynamic and always growing so to do this would be a fairly tedious task.

So while I could just set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `YES` I would much rather have ATS off by default except for my handful of secure HTTPS endpoints. Is it possible to do this? I saw one blog post about someone configuring the plist this way.

[image]

But I cannot find any information verifying that this is a valid solution, nor do I know how to know if a HTTPS request is using ATS. Does anyone know if this is possible or how to know if this is working?

**EDIT**

It's worth mention that the tags in the current app documentation is incorrect.

`NSExceptionAllowInsecureHTTPLoads
NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy
NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion
NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads
NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion
NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy`

Are Actually

`NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads
NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy
NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion
NSTemporaryThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads
NSTemporaryThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion
NSTemporaryThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some more research I was able to answer my own question. So basically you are saying everything needs to default to not using ATS by setting `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` = YES.

But then in your exceptions dictionary(`NSExceptionDomain`) you are specifying endpoints that you want to act differently. So that means you can put your HTTPS endpoints in this list and specify it to use ATS by setting `NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPSLoads` to `NO`. I was able to verify this by putting a unsecure endpoint `itunes.apple.com` and trying to reach it. When I set `NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPSLoads` to `NO` it failed and complained about it not being secure.

This may be obvious to most people but with the little documentation out there I hope this helps.